# How to send/retrieve non-printable characters with text strings to PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, regex, postgresql

WPF PostgreSQL 9.6 C#

After spending the better of today reading what is on the Internet, I still haven't figured out how this is done.

I am trying to encode a "format" tag before a text string. Something like:

> \u0002 (This is the formating area) \u0003 "This is the text string"
>   \u0002 (This is another formating area ) \u0003 "This is another text
>   string" (.....)

That is, each formating area is enclosed by some control-code (i.e., non-printable character) followed by a text message. This then will be repeated for as many messages as I need.

What I want to do ( I don't know how) is to send this entire block of contol-code+message to a WCF method which will then send it to the PostgreSQL backend.

Getting it to WCF is easy, but what is the best method of storing this in PostgreSQL?

Once stored, I need to return it to the client at which time I am hoping to use a two part parser (probably with Regex) to first break the block down into sub-strings of [format]+[Message] and then ultimately to apply each format to its attached message. (Think for loop).

But I do not understand how to get control-codes in an out of PostgreSQL such that I can use Regex to isolate each [format]+Message string back on the client.

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With recent versions of PostgreSQL, you can use `\uXXXX` or `\UXXXXXXXX` escape sequences in string literals if you precede the string literal with `E` to signify that it contains escape sequences:

```
SELECT E'\u0002part 1\u0003\part 2';

┌──────────────────────┐
│       ?column?       │
├──────────────────────┤
│ \x02part 1\x03part 2 │
└──────────────────────┘
(1 row)
```

It is easy to split a string in parts along these lines, see the documentation about PostgreSQL's [string functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html).

For example, if you want to split such a string into an array at either `\u0002` or `\u0003`, you could do it like this:

```
SELECT regexp_split_to_array(
          E'\u0002part 1\u0003\part 2',
          E'[\u0002\u0003]'
       );

┌────────────────────────┐
│ regexp_split_to_array  │
├────────────────────────┤
│ {"","part 1","part 2"} │
└────────────────────────┘
(1 row)
```

Comment: In my useage I would need to form and split the string on the Client Side (i.e., in C#). Using PgAdmin, how can I verify that the correct string is inserted? The \x02 and \x03 are replaced with blank space?

Comment: How is this string with E'\u002' inserted into the database? Did you intend to use Insert above? Thanks.

Comment: I would *not* to use pgAdmin if it causes such problems. Use `psql`. I don't know how pgAdmin displays `bytea`, but if it shows the hex value of the bytes, you could cast your string to `bytea` before displaying it. Then you'll see the `02` and `03` in there. But seriously, why do you store the information is such a format and don't normalize it into a table or at least use a `text[]` for it?

Comment: Ummm... How would you normalize this?? And I've never seen text[] before, please explain.

Comment: By "normalize" I mean that you could create a table with columns `format_string` and `text_string`, a counter and a foreign key to the original table. `text[]` is an [array](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html) of `text`,

Comment: I need to go to work...I'll be back in about 4 hours and give it a shot. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For newbies, (like myself), coming here, a close reading of the [PgAdmin Documentation](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.4/pg/datatype-binary.html) shows that the behavior of PgAdmin depends highly on the column definition used in PostgreSQL. PostgreSQL documentation (if I read it correctly) states that pretty much any encoding can be called a "text" field since internally PostgreSQL defaults to UTF-8 encoding.

By way of example,

```
CREATE TABLE progress_note_drawing_transcription
(
  encounter_recid integer NOT NULL,
  transcription text,
  strokes bytea
)

insert into progress_note_drawing_transcription (encounter_recid, transcription, strokes)
values (111421,E'\u0009 This is a message',E'\u0009 This is a message')
```

But note the following differences:

- When the column of postreSQL is defined as "text", e.g, "transcription" is a text column, then

  select transcription from progress_note_drawing_transcription;

will show " This is a message" where the leading \u0009 is replaced by a space.

- When the column of PostgreSQL is defined as bytea, as in "strokes", then PgAdmin will show:

  select strokes from progress_note_drawing_transcription;

as
    "\011 This is a message"

where 9 is written as an escape octal (base 8).

Furthermore, to see the straight "hex" values, the "text" field in PgAdmin requires:

```
SELECT encode(convert_to(transcription, 'UTF-8'), 'hex') FROM progress_note_drawing_transcription;
```

whereas the "bytea" field can be simply seen as:

```
SELECT encode(strokes, 'hex') FROM progress_note_drawing_transcription;
```

I hope this helps somebody.

(So I guess which is used dependes mostly on personal preference with the one caveat being I think read operations on the "text" data type in postgreSQL is about 15% faster then "bytea" data types. I could be wrong though.)